# PayPal API: What's the difference between PayPalAPI and PayPalAPIAA?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Two different endpoints come out of the WSDL definitions.

bindingConfiguration="PayPalAPISoapBinding" contract="PayPalAPIInterface" name="PayPalAPI"/>

bindingConfiguration="PayPalAPIAASoapBinding" contract="PayPalAPIAAInterface" name="PayPalAPIAA"/>